# Ubuntu 19.04 installer does not recognize my hard drive

Tags: system-installation, hp

I have a HP desktop with Windows 10. I cannot get Ubuntu 19.04 USB install to recognize the hard drive. I also have a second new hard drive installed and the installer does not find that either.

```
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 081502E8-1F23-4AF5-9BD3-73A5468182D6

Device       Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048     923647     921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2   923648    1128447     204800   100M EFI System
/dev/sda3  1128448    1161215      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4  1161216 1953122303 1951961088 930.8G Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/sdf: 15 GiB, 16106127360 bytes, 31457280 sectors
Disk model: USB Disk        
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x46f8e7bf

Device     Boot   Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdf1  *          0 4095999 4096000    2G  0 Empty
/dev/sdf2       4066772 4074259    7488  3.7M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
```

Comment: Is the HDD setup as RAID? Check your BIOS.

Comment: I am In my setup utility, but I cannot find BIOS info?

Comment: BIOS is the basic computer setup function that is usually reached by hitting a function key, like F2, shortly after power on. Check the disk setting, and you'll probably find that it's set to RAID, and that's your problem. Don't change it, just let me know if that's correct, and I'll write an answer that will show you how to change it without disrupting your Windows installation.

Comment: On. Wher r hitting escape key my options are Sys info, Diagnostics, Computer Setup, SYS recovery, Utilities and Run UEFI Application. I cannot seem to find a Disk setting.

Comment: Found it...SATA Emulation: AHCI

Comment: Other options are RAID & IDE

Comment: Hum, then I don't know what's wrong. AHCI is correct. Sorry.